# iPhone and iPad can't find each other via bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, bluetooth, gamekit

I have an iPhone 4s and an iPad 2 which should be able to establish a connection via bluetooth.
Bluetooth is activated on both devices, and both are scanning for other devices, but none of them shows up on the other one.

If i turn on the personal hotspot on the iPhone, both devices find each other.

Sadly, this is not a solution for me, because I´m writing an app which should establish the connection (using GameKit), so the user must not be forced to activate the personal hotspot before using the app.

So my question is: Is there anything I am missing, to make both iOS devices see each other without using the personal hotspot function?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't know, what are you trying now?

Comment: the goal is to make the devices visible to each other in iOS, because then it will also work for GameKit (as far as I could test it for now).

Comment: Only devices that can be paired and are supported show up in the Settings.app, if you use `GKSession` they will be able to find and connect automatically without having to be paired by the user...

Comment: @jjv360 strangely, that wasn´t the case. Now everything works fine, but i´ll have to test if the problem reoccurs, as soon as two devices, that didn´t know each other before, try to connect.

Answer (score 1):

iPad 2 is **NOT** supporting BLE 4.0 and it has different hardware module for bluetooth. Maybe that's the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the session id in both is the same, or they will not find each other.

```
- (GKSession *)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker sessionForConnectionType:    (GKPeerPickerConnectionType)type{
GKSession* session = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"com.cilk.id" displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
return [session autorelease];
```

}